# Move two VIewPagers simultaneously in one gesture

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I need to make a slide transition in 2 distinct ViewPagers in one slide gesture to either of them. How can I go about that?

Comment: Add your existing code so that we can help you.

Comment: Why did you go with two `ViewPager`s, if you want them to behave as one `ViewPager`?

Comment: Actually I need screen that when swipe down is detected, one view should be displayed and on swipe up another view should be displayed. Both of these views should be horizontally swipable. That's why i made two viewpagers. But I can't sync the two viewpagers. I catched the touch event of either of the ViewPager and then transferred that touch event to the other one, still that throws Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in your OnPageChangeListener in ViewPager class

```
public void onPageSelected(int position)
{
    secondViewPager.setCurrentItem(position, true);
}
```

Comment: This is not what I want. Your technique will cause transition only once. What if I need to keep sticking in the middle of transition.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will **slide both the ViewPagers simultaneously whether there size is same or not**:

```
viewPagerBanner.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    private int scrollState = ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;
    // Indicates that the pager is in an idle, settled state. 
    // The current page is fully in view and no animation is in progress.

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, 
                               int positionOffsetPixels) {
        if (scrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            return;
        }
        viewPagerTitle.scrollTo(viewPagerBanner.getScrollX()*
                                viewPagerTitle.getWidth()/
                                viewPagerBanner.getWidth(), 0);
        // We are not interested in Y axis position
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        scrollState = state;
        if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            viewPagerTitle.setCurrentItem(viewPagerBanner.getCurrentItem(), false);
        }
    }
});
```

Use the same code for the another ViewPager.